# Two domains on Exchange for same users, but not in same inbox?

Tags: exchange

I have let's say domain x.com and domain y.com.

My users needs to get mail from both x and y, but due to legal reasons, the mail must not be in same mailbox. I guess if I exchange opens the user and under SMTP enter user@x.com and user@y.com it will end in the same mailbox, which is not legal in my case.

Can a user have several "Inboxes" (physical splitted mail files) in Exchange?

I hope you know what I mean - it's difficult to explain.

Thx, Mojo

Comment: Could you have two exchange servers that both authenticated with a single active directory server?

Comment: Hi, emmmm no, becuase we're a small company (on 16 employies), so having two exchange servers will be overkill. :)

Comment: You could create a bare metal hypervisor and then install the two exchange servers on it. That way you save the resources of having to dedicate another physical computer.